# The way you were dancing as if you were a snake in your past life

Tags: grammar

'The way you were dancing as if you were a snake in your past life'

Is this sentence correct to say?

Answer (score 1):

**This is not grammatically correct.**

In its current form, this is a [sentence fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Incomplete_sentence) composed of two dependent clauses:

The subject of the fragment is "the way you were dancing", a [content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause).

"As if you were a snake in your past life" is a [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause).

**To be a sentence, the fragment would require a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar))** - For example:

> **I liked** the way you were dancing as if you were a snake in your past life
>
> The way you were dancing **was** as if you were a snake in your past life
>
> You were dancing as if you were a snake in your past life

In the first example, **I** becomes the subject of the sentence. **Liked** is the predicate, with the original fragment as the object.

In the second, **The way you were dancing** is the subject, with **was** as the predicate and **as if you were a snake in your past life** as the object.

Finally, in the third example, the first clause is split into **You** (subject), **were** (predicate), and **dancing** (object). **Dancing** is a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English) modified by "as if you were a snake in your past life".

Note, however, that English is often not used grammatically correctly, particularly in informal contexts. In some situations, such as song lyrics, this may be an acceptable "sentence".